# Making up a 1/2" difference in subfloor level

Tags: flooring

I have linoleum flooring in the kitchen that is about ~1/2 inch raised from the floor. There is 1/4 ply and two layers of linoleum.

I'll be putting down vinyl flooring and I want to extend it to the rest of the house without a reducer.

I looked for underlayment options but the largest that I found so far is 6mm. Is there another cheap material that I can use for this? The rest of the floor space is 1000 sq ft so it has to be something cost effective.

Comment: Can we assume that the rest of the house needs underlayment regardless? Does it have rough subfloor now? Have you investigated removing the existing flooring, so that new underlayment in the other areas brings things level?

Comment: It is all pretty much the same thick ply subfloor. I could stack up two layers of steico wood fiber or cork but then cost goes up. Plywood is somewhat cheaper but still expensive. I think sadly I may have to accept the reducer since it is the cheapest choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a soft underlayment that's that thick, 1/2". You will probably need to lay down 1/2" plywood and then add your flooring on top of that.

There are many reducer transition pieces if you should decide to keep the new floor lower than the existing one. I know you stated you don't want that but it might end up being a viable alternative.

Comment: Yes, a plywood of sufficient grade would qualify as underlayment.

Comment: @isherwood Clarification:  would the plywood be a sub floor  or underlayment?  I thought underlayment was a thin cushion, sound proof layer.

Comment: @isherwood and Jack To me subfloor is the structural material laid directly on the joists and is walked on, scuffed, etc. during construction. The underlayment is a finish material laid on the subfloor and is kept in good condition for the finish flooring. A good underlayment for most materials (including tile) is underlayment grade plywood which has holes plugged and top layer is “touch sanded” and specifically made for underlayment use.

Comment: Jack, you're confusing soft underlayments (padding, really) that are commonly associated with floating floors and conventional _hard_ underlayment, which is required under sheet vinyl. We're talking about the latter in this case. It's usually thin-ply 1/4" birch these days, but it used to be 1/2" particle board.